# Powerquery webscraping: Adding multiple columns without requesting the same webpage anew for every column

Tags: excel, powerquery

My base table holds the links to subpages of the same website and I want to add multiple columns with scraped values. The `Table.AddColumn()` function provides the appropriate link through its iterator functionality and the simplest way would be to request the website, select the value and add it to the new column, which is quite inefficient though, because the exact same list of web requests would be made for every new column.

The next best solution would be to only add one column, concatenate all relevant values to a string before passing them to be added and finally split the string column into multiple columns. That works but doesn't seem like the intended way to me.

Is there a better solution that still doesn't request any page more than once?

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, each row in your table represents a URL and you only want to request each URL once.

1. Create a column using `Table.AddColumn` in which you only request the page, but don't actually do anything with the response yet. (So this newly added column will only contain the server's response.)
2. Then start adding the rest of the columns (with `Table.AddColumn`) with their respective logic as you did before -- except now, instead of requesting the page again, you can refer to the column you created in step 1 since that column contains the response you'd receive if you were to request it again.
3. You can remove the column from step 1 (using `Table.RemoveColumns`) once you no longer need it.

I think your problem was to do with scope. You were requesting and extracting in the same function and only returning the extracted value (meaning the response went out of scope when the function finished, meaning you'd need to request the response again if you wanted to work with it again -- which you did).

I would give you some example code, but you've not included any code in your question.

Comment: Thank you Madam/Sir! That's what I had in mind but couldn't think of haha